# Is it possible to change a string class member in another class?

Tags: java

I have a class in `theFirst.java` file.

```
public class theFirst {
    private String str = "Hello , i'm here";
    public IntStream get_code_point(){
        return str.codePoints();
    }
    public void str_print(){
        System.out.println(str);
    }
    public String get_str(){
        return str;
    }
}
```

In another class in `for_test.java`, I want to get a string to add something to it and have it change too:

```
public class for_test {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        theFirst tmp = new theFirst();
        String test2 = tmp.get_str();
        test2+= "another one";
        tmp.str_print();
        System.out.println(test2);       
    }
}
```

But for some reason, when called `tmp.str_print();`. The line has not changed, but if i print
`System.out.println(test2);` then prints the modified one.

I am new to java and as I understand such classes should pass a reference, but as I understand copying occurs.I'll be glad if you can help me figure it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 1):

Following

```
test2 += "another one";
```

doesn't works as you expect it to because `tmp.get_str()` returns a string to which you concatenate another string: `"another one"`. This concatenation creates a new string: `"Hello , i'm hereanother one"` which is then assigned to `test2` BUT the `temp.str` is unaffected; it's value isn't changed.

Strings are immutable - you have to create a new string and then assign it to `str` instance field.

To do this, you first need a setter method:

```
public String setStr(String str){
    this.str = str;
}
```

Inside the `main` method, call this setter method as:

```
tmp.setStr(tmp.get_str() + "another one");
```

or you can do it in two steps: first create a string and then pass the new string to the setter method:

```
test2 += "another one";
tmp.setStr(test2);
```

---

Alternatively, you could create a method inside the `theFirst` class that does the concatenation for you.

```
public void concatenateStr(String str) {
   this.str += str;
}
```

Inside the `main` method, you can call it as:

```
tmp.concatenateStr("another one");
```

---

**Note:** Class names should begin with a capital letter: `theFirst` should be: `TheFirst` or simply: `First`.